# How to get the return address of a function in C?

Tags: c

I have a function called:

```
doSomething()
```

The way I understand this is: In assembly, this will jump to the function location and store the function's return address in some register so that after the function is done, the program counter can return to the main program.

How do I get this function's return address and put this inside a variable so that I can use it?

*__builtin_return_address* doesn't seem to be working. When I translate it to assembly, it doesn't know what to do. I believe I can't use GCC. I'm not even using printf since its not a part of the standard C library.

Currently, I'm trying to guess what its return address is by putting various numbers inside this variable.

Comment: C language does not define implementation details, like return addresses, stacks, and others. What it does define is semantics (behaviour) of language constructs. I am afraid you cannot get the return address without using assembly or some low-level (and compiler specific) intrinsics. What do you want to use the return address for? Perhaps there is some C functionality which could be used to achieve what you want.

Comment: "store the function's return address in some register" Most implementations will store (push) the return address to the stack. The RET instruction then gets (pops) the address and jumps to it.

Comment: What do you want to do with this address? Note that it only exists when `doSomething` is executing, that is, if you can get the return address of a function at all, you can only get it within the function itself.

Comment: You may want to look at `setjump()` and `longjump()` in '#include <setjump.h>` those are the portable ways of returning to anything other than the direct calling function.

Comment: There is not portable C solution to get the return address of a function.

Comment: @solidwaterslayer: You're correct: "In assembly, this will jump to the function location". And you CAN (effectively) "put this [address] inside a variable so that I can use it". There are several ways to accomplish this, including [inline assembly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_assembler). I suggested "function pointers" [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64651938/421195) to parameterize the callee's address. 
 Use [setjmp](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setjmp.3.html) to parameterize the *caller's* address. Q: Does this help answer your question?

Comment: I want the return address of doSomething() because later I would like to return to the same return address. Kind of like, going back in time.

Answer (score 4):

With `gcc` you can use `__builtin_return_address`, see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Return-Address.html

Answer (score 2):

Another user here posted about using gcc which I agree with, but storing it as a variable is simply by using a void data type, kind of like this:

`void *addr = __builtin_extract_return_addr (__builtin_return_address (0));`

Answer (score -3):

C and C++ support [function pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_pointer):

C Example:

```
int sum (int num1, int num2) {
  return num1 + num2;
}

int (*f2p) (int, int);

int main (int argc, char (argv[]) {
    f2p = sum;
    printf ("sum=%d\n", f2p(10, 13));
    return 0;
}
```

In C++, you'd use [std::function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function).

Here is a good tutorial:

https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/78-function-pointers/

You do *NOT* need to worry about the binary memory address of the function in order to use function pointers.  If, for whatever reason you *wanted*; just cast the address (e.g. "fp2" above) to a number.

---

I'm suggesting "function pointers" to parameterize the callee's address.

As Persixty suggested, you can use [setjmp()](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setjmp.3.html)/[longjmp()](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/longjmp.3.html) to parameterize the *caller's* address.

Of course, you can also use [inline assembly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_assembler) to accomplish either.

Q: Does this help answer your question?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.